# Preventing laptop wake up when opening the lid on linux

Tags: linux, laptop, power, wake-up

My laptop is broken and the lid does not lock. So I want it not to wake up when the lid is open. I use ubuntu, but gnome-power-preferences does not have any option like that (only to close the lid).

Is there any way to do this? I'm afraid next time it opens on the case it will get burned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I [found a way](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=293883) after googleing a bit smarter (it was difficult to find the correct search keys).

In short, the file `/proc/acpi/wakeup` has a line for `LID` which is enabled.

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup 
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PCIB      S4     disabled  pci:0000:00:1e.0
USB1      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
USB2      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.1
USB3      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.2
USB4      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.3
USB7      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.7
MODM      S3     disabled  
HDEF      S3     disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
PXS1      S4     disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
LID       S4    *enabled
```

If you `echo " LID" > /proc/acpi/wakeup` it will change to disable and the computer won't wake up on lid open.

Follow the instructions on the already mentioned link to set it permanent on your computer.

Comment: What if that file doesn't have that line? Can I just add it?

Comment: I'm getting `bash: /proc/acpi/wakeup: Permission denied`. What to do? (This is in LinuxMint 8.3)

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the BIOS parameters of my computer and found no "event at lid open" to configure. Using KDE on Debian, I found no such parameter in the main configuration window either. Moreover, my `/proc/acpi/wakeup` file does not include any `LID` line. So the previous answers do not work for all systems.

Nevertheless, setting up files based on [this suggestion](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1635839&sid=6208234fece900a18a9f97c4744e67e2#p1635839) (and especially [its corrected contents](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1635939&sid=6208234fece900a18a9f97c4744e67e2#p1635939)) may solve the problem for any Linux system.

I just advise to type the following line as `root`, and then try and close/open the lid after going to suspend mode, just to check that that solution works for your system before actually setting up the files:

`echo disabled | sudo tee /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/power/wakeup`

Comment: it also issues that screen (display) does not turn off, when closing lid. So it prevents all event triggering assigned to lid output

Answer (score 0):

Usually wake is not triggered once lid is open. If you get running system once you open lid, your system was probably not in S3 sleep as it should have been. Probably there is something preventing full sleep.

Additionally you can look in BIOS for wake-up events and turn off those that you don't want (maybe lid wake is among them).

Comment: This is a fujitsu lifebook, I don't see nothing like this on the BIOS. I use the 'normal' suspend command from gnome-power-cmd.

Answer (score 0):

running `echo " LID" > /proc/acpi/wakeup` as root will disable it but to make it permanent you have to create a service so first cd to `/etc/systemd/system/`
then create file like `your-service-name.service`  
then your file should be like this :

```
[Unit]
Description=no wakeup when lid is open

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '[ "$(cat /proc/acpi/wakeup |grep -P -o "LID.*\*\K\w+")" == "enabled" ] && echo "LID" > /proc/acpi/wakeup'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then Reload the service files to include the new service :

```bsh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start your service:

```
sudo systemctl start your-service-name.service
```

enable your service on every reboot:

```
sudo systemctl enable example.service
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).