# Linux power management: is it possible to wake up on lid open only and ignore lid close?

Tags: linux, laptop, power-management, systemd, suspend

```
uname -a
Linux 820g3 5.9.1-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat, 17 Oct 2020 13:30:37 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In /etc/systemd/logind.conf:

If `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` then laptop goes to sleep on lid close and wakes up on lid open.

If `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` then laptop ignores lid action.

Is it possible to **wake up on lid open only** and **ignore lid close**?

Comment: Does this https://superuser.com/questions/67814/preventing-laptop-wake-up-when-opening-the-lid-on-linux solve the problem? Though the behaviour is the opposite of what you want, the method is the same, I suppose.

Comment: That post reminds me to check the BIOS options where a toggle for wake up on lid open is found :)